# Unable to install software "Eclipse Search CSV Export" in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, csv, error-log

When I am trying to install a new plugin, Eclipse Search CSV Export, in Eclipse I am getting the following error:

> Unable to connect to repository http://csv-export.sourceforge.net/update.site.xml. org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException. 
>       Connection to https://nchc.dl.sourceforge.net refused.

May I know what can be done to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Its possible to install the plugin directly from the web browser by dragging the install icon from: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-search-csv-export into your eclipse.

If the problem still persists, it's probably a proxy issue. You can find out how to resolve it [here](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-net-preferences.htm). You could also check [this](https://www.mkyong.com/web-development/how-to-configure-proxy-settings-in-eclipse/) out.

Answer (score 0):

That link seems to be broken.

```
jonathan@JON-W541-W10:/mnt/c/Users/Jonathan/Downloads$ wget http://csv-export.sourceforge.net/update.site.xml
--2017-04-19 09:11:05--  http://csv-export.sourceforge.net/update.site.xml
Resolving csv-export.sourceforge.net (csv-export.sourceforge.net)... 216.34.181.96
Connecting to csv-export.sourceforge.net (csv-export.sourceforge.net)|216.34.181.96|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://master.dl.sourceforge.net/project/csv-export/update/.site.xml [following]
--2017-04-19 09:11:06--  http://master.dl.sourceforge.net/project/csv-export/update/.site.xml
Resolving master.dl.sourceforge.net (master.dl.sourceforge.net)... 216.34.181.56
Connecting to master.dl.sourceforge.net (master.dl.sourceforge.net)|216.34.181.56|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-04-19 09:11:06 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

The following link works though:

http://csv-export.sourceforge.net/update/site.xml